# How to convert a string of numbers into a list of int in python3

Tags: string, list, python-3.x

sample input:

```
32 42 4 423 43 2 3
```

my code to convert the input into a list of integers:

```
mylist = map(int, (list(input().split(' '))))
print(mylist)
```

output of my code:

```
<map object at 0x7f0eb38f1d30>
```

Expected output:

```
[32, 42, 4, 423, 43, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a list use a list comprehension:

```
mylist = [int(x) for x in input.split(' ')]
```

The result of map is a map object, and you're getting it's representation.

You can convert it to a list:

```
mymap = map(int, (list(input().split(' '))))
print(list(mymap))
```

Comment: `map()` has such a useless output, why didn't the python3 writers make it return a list by default? When is `<map object at 0x7f0eb38f1d30>` ever useful?

Comment: When you don't need the list. If you're applying a function to a very long list it's often wasteful to build it in memory.